# Symfony 4 Regex, find a pattern that excludes email check from url check

Tags: php, regex, forms, symfony

I have a Symfony form that has fields that should let users write emails but not URLs.
I am currently using this regex:

```
return new Regex(
        [
            'pattern' => '((http|https|ftp|ftps)://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(/[a-zA-Z0-9=.?&-]*)?',
            'match'   => false,
            'message' => $this->translator->trans('form.field.urlNotAllowed', ['%label%' => $label])
        ]
    );
```

This regex matches all URLs, but also match emails for validation.
What I want to do is excluding emails from validation and match only URLs.

My code:

```
/**
 * @param RegistrationFormField $field
 * @param string $key
 * @param array $validationAttributes
 * @return Regex
 */
public function getUrlNotAllowedConstraint($field, $key, &$validationAttributes)
{
    $event = $field->getRegistrationForm()->getEvent();

    $label = /** @Ignore */
    $this->translator->trans($field->getLabel(), [], 'custom') ?: $this->getDefaultLabelName($event, $key);
    
    $validationAttributes['data-validation'][] = 'url_not_allowed';

    return new Regex(
        [
            'pattern' => '((http|https|ftp|ftps)://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(/[a-zA-Z0-9=.?&-]*)?',
            'match'   => false,
            'message' => $this->translator->trans('form.field.urlNotAllowed', ['%label%' => $label])
        ]
    );
}
```

Any help?

I have created the CustomSequentically Constraint:

```
namespace App\Form\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Composite as 
ConstraintsComposite;

/**
* Use this constraint to sequentially validate nested 
constraints.
* Validation for the nested constraints collection will stop at 
first violation.
*
* @Annotation
* @Target({"CLASS", "PROPERTY", "METHOD", "ANNOTATION"})
*
*/
class CustomSequentially extends ConstraintsComposite
{
    public $constraints = [];

    public function getDefaultOption()
    {
        return 'constraints';
    }

    public function getRequiredOptions()
    {
        return ['constraints'];
    }

    protected function getCompositeOption()
    {
        return 'constraints';
    }

    public function getTargets()
    {
        return [self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT, self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT];
    }
}
```

And the CustomSequentiallyValidator Class:

```
namespace App\Form\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class CustomSequentiallyValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof CustomSequentially) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, CustomSequentially::class);
        }

        $context = $this->context;

        $validator = $context->getValidator()->inContext($context);

        $originalCount = $validator->getViolations()->count();

        foreach ($constraint->constraints as $c) {
            if ($originalCount !== $validator->validate($value, $c)->getViolations()->count()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And used the constraint like this:

```
    $constraints = new CustomSequentially([
        'constraints' => [
             new Regex([
                'pattern' => '/((http|https|ftp|ftps):\/\/)?((?!@)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(\/[a-zA-Z0-9=.?&-]*)?/',
                'match'   => false,
                'message' => $this->translator->trans('form.field.urlNotAllowed', ['%label%' => $label])
            ]),
            new Regex([
                'pattern' => '/[@]/',
                'match'   => true,
                'message' => 'It is an email'
            ]),
        ],
    ]);
    return $constraints;
```

Now, if I write a URL or an email both are not passing the validation(a simple text is passing).

Comment: You could use the [URL Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Url.html).

Comment: @Bossman it is including emails also!

Comment: Ah okay, you could use the url constraint and the regex constraint that just checks for the @ in the string.. I would probably create my own custom validation using these..

Comment: @Bossman any example how to do that? I mean I know how to create a custom validation, but how to make the double check work?

Comment: In your form you can add multiple constants [like this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#form-validation).

Comment: @Bossman The second constraint should be depended by the first one I think, so i should get the result from the first constraint(which checks if there is a URL written(if it is it will return an error so the second constraint will not be executed in this situation)) and after that check the second constraint. So I don't think that adding multiple constraints to form will be a solution.

Comment: You can pack them together with the [Sequentially Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Sequentially.html) to achieve what you are after..

Comment: @Bossman The project is on Symfony 4, Secuentially Constraint is from version 5.1 and up. Any similar solution?

Comment: I see, here is the [Sequentially blob](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/Sequentially.php) from github. You could copy this and try using it as a custom constraint in your project..

Comment: Would this work for you as regex slightly modified from yours `((http|https|ftp|ftps):\/\/)?((?!@)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(\/[a-zA-Z0-9=.?&-]*)?` added `(?!@)` group..

Comment: @Bossman It is matching the email domain(ex. test@gmail.com -> matches the domain 'gmail.com')

Comment: @Bossman I have modified the answer and added the custom constraint I made (same as you mentioned), but with no results. Just to mention, I've used the match => false because I want the validation to be passed if the string dont match the regex for url.

Comment: I have posted an answer after thinking about it, forget the sequential etc.., that should work for you, this is how i would do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow any string but if it is a URL it will check with regex. If it detects a URL it will then see if it is an email address by checking if the URL contains the `@` symbol and allow it.

Improve or iterate on for your needs as you see fit.

**The Constraint**

```
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class NoUrl extends Constraint
{
    public $urlMessage = 'This looks like a URL, this is not valid.';
}
```

**The Validator**

```
namespace App\Validator;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedValueException;

class NoUrlValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{

    public function validate($url, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof NoUrl) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, NoUrl::class);
        }

        if (null === $url || '' === $url) {
            return;
        }

        if (!is_string($url)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException($url, 'string');
        }

        if (preg_match('/((http|https|ftp|ftps):\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(\/[a-zA-Z0-9=.?&-]*)?/', trim($url))) {
            // str_contains() is PHP 8+, use strpos() for PHP <8
            // String contains an @ symbol so just return as it must be an email address. You can add more checks if needed yourself.
            if (str_contains($url, '@')) {
                return;
            }

            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->urlMessage)->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

**In Your Form**

```
...
use App\Validator\NoUrl;

class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('yourfield', TextType::class, array(
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NoUrl()
                )
            ))
...
```

Comment: I am trying to do the opposite => on the input(every type of form inputs), I need to let users write anything(including any string or any email) but not URL. THe solution you provided is blocking me from writting simple text( the 'test' word), it is also blocking my selects, if I write an email it is blocking again, also is I write a URL

Comment: Sorry, i did not 100% understand you. It's difficult as the email has also the domain portion. Updated.

Comment: I founded a solution, FINALLY haha.

Comment: With some logical modifications, yes! $base = "((http|https|ftp|ftps)://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}(/[a-zA-Z0-9=.?&-]*)?"; if (preg_match("#$base#", $url)) {if (preg_match("#\s($base)#", " $url")) { $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();}}}

Comment: Can you edit the answer with the code I wrote on the comment, so I can add it as a correct answer :). Thanks for all the help!

Comment: How about just doing `..., trim($url)` in *preg_match*, if that's what you're trying to go for, removing all whitespace before and after?

Comment: No, I actually first checked if the string is a URL, and if it is then I checked if the string is an email and if it is I don't trigger a violence, I only do trigger a violence if it is a URL and not an email( so the double check I told you on the beginning). This also fixed the allowence to write simple texts.

Comment: Updated, just put the check for `@` within the *preg_match* case.